# PHP script to detect the browser language, what about the google bot?

Tags: php, seo, googlebot

I am working on a website that will be avalaible on two language (english and french). I made a script to detect the browser language with     $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] and depending on the result I load an xml file where all the text are written.
I was wondering if this is a problem for the SEO, as I guess the google bot will get the english version but not the french?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following link in your head to advertise the other language. An example for the french homepage:

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="/?lang=en">`

Otherwise Google cannot know and will only index one language (from my experience)

See: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077

Comment: I'll have to change a few thing as I am using a session variable to save the language, but I have the answer I wanted, thanks!